# How can make schedule job in Python to pop elements of the list?

Tags: python, schedule

I want to pop each element of `string` list below for every given time interval.

I have tried following code at my end but every time it fetches only last element.

```py
import schedule
import time
def job():
    #print("I'm working...")
    string = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print (string.pop())



schedule.every(0.1).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The result I am getting is `4` `4` `4` `4`. I expect `4` `3` `2` `1`.

Comment: Every time `job()` runs, it executes `string = [1, 2, 3, 4]` all over again.  That needs to be outside the function, so it happens only one time (and then you need code to handle the case of running out of items).

Comment: Oh yes! That's silly mistake :)

Comment: Is it okay to handle that case with `while len(string):` ? Or any other better solution?